# How do I output just a string in a line with grep, given part of the string?

Tags: linux, unix

I want to output just a certain string in a line, based off of a partial piece of that string.

```
string1alsa;kdjfsdf string2 string3
string1saldkfjsa;df string 4 string5
```

I'm expecdting output to be

```
string1alsa;kdjfsdf,string1saldkfjsa;df
```

based off of the partial string `string1`

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm unsure.

Comment: I don't understand the desired output.

Comment: So you want to get everything around `string1` up to the space, and also combine the results onto a single line?

Comment: Is `string1` always in the first field on the line?

Answer (score 0):

`grep -oe '\S*string1\S*' file.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'`